# Why doesn't SQL Server recognise a stored procedure but it runs it without error?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures

I am using MSSQL Management Studio.  I have creates a stored procedure using CREATE PROCEDURE and am now working on it with a script that now contains ALTER PROCEDURE.  The procedure name following this statement is underlined in red, and the editor says it cannot find it.  Nevertheless, the stored procedure appears in the left-hand tree view, and I can right-click it and run it without error.  When I do this, the temporary script that is generated to run the stored procedure...

```
EXEC @return_value = [dbo].[SP_V00_CreateABCTable]
```

also underlines the name in red.

I don't understand how the editor can claim the object doesn't exist but then runs it without error.  Does anyone have any idea what may be going on?

Comment: This is just intellisense in management studio.

Answer (score 7):

Or you can also refresh your local cache form here

[image]

Answer (score 3):

This happens frequently if you have created the stored proc since you opened the SQL manager studio session. Refreshing the Object Explorer does not refresh this data for the syntax checker. Opening a new instance of studio will refresh the intellisense data.

Comment: Ctrl+Shift+R will refresh local cache, no need to open a new instance of SSMS.